# How to refer to yourself in the anonymous class?

Tags: kotlin

I have next code in `kotlin`:

```
handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                Timber.i("run post msg")
                handler.postDelayed(this, AppPrefs.SEARCH_DELAY)
            }
        },AppPrefs.SOCKET_INTERVAL)
```

how you see it's simple standard way to create delayed task (with `Runnable` `class`). Value `this` references to anonimus Object implements `Runnable` and compile and works fine

But when i make lamdba for this:

```
handler.postDelayed({
            Timber.i("run post msg")
            handler.postDelayed(this, AppPrefs.SOCKET_INTERVAL)
        },AppPrefs.SOCKET_INTERVAL)
```

value `this` referenced to outher class.

How referenced from inner anonimus class to yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do this. A [similar question](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-this-accessible-in-sams/1477/2) was asked on Kotlin's forum and yole (one of the creators of the language) said this:

> `this` in a lambda refers to the instance of the containing class, if any. A lambda is conceptually a function, not a class, so there is no such thing as a lambda instance to which `this` could refer.
>
> The fact that a lambda can be converted into an instance of a SAM interface does not change `this`. Having this in a lambda mean different things depending on whether the lambda gets SAM-converted would be extremely confusing.